# Gmail displaying "me" instead of actual sender's name

Tags: gmail

When viewing my inbox, I would like to display the sender's name according to the email's header.  Meaning, if I send an email to myself from my gmail address, but give the from name as Freddie Flintoff, I want Freddie Flintoff to appear instead of "me".

Answer (score -1):

There is special handling for "me" and you cannot override this.

Edit: This is handled by [`MessageHeaderView.getRecipientSummaryText(…)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/master/src/com/android/mail/browse/MessageHeaderView.java#708) where `myName` is `"me"` (in English).

Comment: [Half line answers — what would be the best course of action(s) to deal with them?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2032/119358)

Comment: This isn't an half-line answer. There is currently no possibility to do what the OP asks.

Comment: What @Manubhargav means is that this answer is a bit hard to understand without some background and/or description (sources?) for what you posit.